# Building a configuration application for a hierarchy of Ordered Collections with MVC 4 and EntityFramework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-4

I'm trying to build a configuration application for a hierarchy of ordered collections. I would like to be able to change the order of items. Ideally the entire hierarchy would be editable (and reorderable) on one page, with persistence on post. Is there an easy way to do this?

I'm trying to build a configuration application for restaurant menus. They need to have ordered sections with ordered items under each section.

So far I've seen components that can accomplish parts of this, including jQuery sortable, but nothing that accomplishes the whole thing.

What would your approach be?